# distortion using Elektron Syntakt as an audio interface

Tags: sound, jack, pipewire

I'm having a strange problem trying to use an Elektron Syntakt as an audio interface via USB. The thing is that this worked without any problems or special configuration in Ubuntu Studio 22.04, but the sound is completely distorted in 23.04.

I've disabled pipewire and tried different Jack parameters, disabled pulseaudio... but the problem is the same every time. Jack server complains about "XRUN overruns", no matter the configuration I try.

It works fine with another audio interface (Audient id14) without any special configuration.

Any insight into this will be greatly appreciated!

Googling, I've found some people with similar problems, but no solutions.